# Port 80 blocked on cpanel due to phpunit malicious file eval-stdin.php

Tags: php, phpunit, cpanel, google-signin, port80

I have added google plus login to my website (hosted on shared server). While composing dependent libraries through composer.json for google login, the phpunit library was downloaded as a part. It contains a file phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\PHP\eval-stdin.php. Due to this file port 80 for my domain is blocked as they said its a malware file.
The repository link is https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit

Following is the code in eval-stdin.php file 
`eval('?>' . file_get_contents('php://input'));`
Is there any alternative to this code. How can i fix this issue. please help

Comment: In my opinion these type of development tools shouldn't be downloaded by composer unless some sort of development flag is set. I had a project also download PHPUnity, I'm sure we're not the only ones.

Answer (score 8):

PHPUnit is a tool to be used during development. You should not upload it to your server.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, i didn't know that.. :)