# Port 80 get blocked when I am uploading laravel 5.1 project to server

Tags: laravel, cpanel

Whenever I am trying to upload(using FTP) laravel 5.1 project to server(BigRock shared Hosting). Everything runs fine but after some time my port 80 gets block. Then I can't send any SMS.

When I am using Cpanel Upload option then it shows virus is there in laravel file. So I have decided to upload only laravel fresh folder which was downloaded from official source with other system, same problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

to see why your port 80 is blocked you check it from cpanel's Health cehck and monitoring section.

In my site it says that a file in phpunit

```
public_html/illuminati/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php
```

is a malware file.

I searched for this on stackoverflow and found the answer. PHPUnit is only for development purpose. You should not upload that. I deleted it from sever and it works for me [Port 80 blocked on cpanel due to phpunit malicious file eval-stdin.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378482/port-80-blocked-on-cpanel-due-to-phpunit-malicious-file-eval-stdin-php)

Answer (score 0):

Your antivirus server is detecting some component as a virus or another malware so it blocks the HTTP server to block the virus spreading. 
You should talk with your hosting company and explain the problem

Answer (score 0):

In my opinon as a hoster, I can tell you that the issue is not laravel, not Cpanel.

This is the server where these have enabled with misconfiguration [CXS ConfigServer Exploit Scanner](http://configserver.com/cp/cxs.html), a dangerous combination with blacklist. The result is a false positive when you try to upload files through Cpanel.

It is also probable that have enabled security mod, next to a rules using a series of lists. Verify that your IP is not blacklisted with [Spamhaus](https://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/) and [MXToolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)